# Using data held in an SQL database in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

So far, I have created 3 tables in SQL using visual studio. They have been connected to my VB project file and I can view the data held within them using the Database Explorer.

My only problem is: how do I use/make available the data held within each table?

I need to write code which will add a Japanese character (from one of the tables that already exists) to a new table when a check box is ticked. Then I need to write code to update the table and save the changes.

I have absolutely no idea how to retrieve the data held in each table nor how to write a SQL query in VB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to write a query to extract data from your database. There are many ways to do this - ADO.NET and Entity Framework are popular choices. I strongly suggest to read one of thousands of online tutorials that explain how to do this.

Comment: How would I use ADO.NET and Entity Framework?

Comment: I suggest tutorials only because your question is completely vague - it encompasses multiple aspects of web programming. I suggest to do some basic tutorials that explain the technologies and how to use them. After doing a tutorial or two and following some examples you will understand how to use it. Once you have a grasp on ADO, then you can ask a specific question about why does "YXZ not work."

Comment: ADO.NET has introduced me to LINQ and has helped teach me some of the syntax required; so thank you very much!